# Calculate tax on sales price excluding discount

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have tried to calculate tax excluding discounted code but it will calculate tax on discounted price.

**woocommerce**

How to calculate tax on sales price when the discount is applied so I want to exclude discount in sales tax

The scenario is that  sales price is  50 
                  discount is 15%
                  tax is 20%
I want to calculate tax on sales price not on discounted price.

Comment: Please read : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask